# Retrieving the userid from my database firebase with the the value of location coordinate and display in android googlemap

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers

im making an app which saves the location coordinates longitude and latitude, actually i already retrieved the coordinates which have been saved in firebase database. Now my problem is i dont know how to get the userID of my coordinates. This is how i retrieved it:

```
 Query transactionQuery = databasePassenger.child("TRANSACTIONS");
    transactionQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get user value
            List<Locate> locationData = new ArrayList<>();

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                muser_id = postSnapshot.getKey();

                locationData.add(postSnapshot.getValue(Locate.class));
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < locationData.size(); i++){

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(locationData.get(i).getLatitude(),locationData.get(i).getLongitude());


                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE)));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "lat: " + locationData.get(i).getLatitude()
                        + "long : " + locationData.get(i).getLongitude() +"\n" + muser_id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
```

And this is the structure of my database:

```js
TRANSACTIONS
 -2jjD1ENf9XatwvWl4V3IMk9syM62
    latitude:10.2941843
    longitude:123.8976738
 -tFvIQN11LJMRyK8gklgJFdtITF32
    latitude: 10.2941843
    longitude:123.8976738
 -wtPbYkyTbEStzhNceRzSteH3vxc2
    latitude: 10.2898739
    longitude: 123.8612526
```

When i declare `muser_id = postSnapshot.getKey();` only 1 userid has been retrieved intead of 3.

Comment: Which userid gets returned? Also, if you put this code `Log.e("Count " ,""+dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());` right after you create your arrayList, what does it return?

Comment: @taurus the `muser_id` returns the last child in the database,  the `wtPbYkyTbEStzhNceRzSteH3vxc2addclose` and the `Log` returns **3** counts